# No ChatJax in Android Chrome Browser?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, mobile-web, mobile-chrome

There has been [a similar previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309605/382397), but it did not catch a lot of attention.

I am a pretty active member of the Physics.se and frequently take part in chats with the people down there. And quite a few times we delve into physics and maths stuff and write equations to make our points clearer. But my browser does not show them in a formatted view; all I can see is the LaTeX code they write.

This becomes frustrating at times because it's quite uncomfortable switching between tabs all the time to see what is written.

Is this a bug in the chat window? Or is the feature unavailable in the browser version?

If the former, please fix it quickly. If the latter, then it would be a great help to the Stack Exchange community if this feature is involved.

(Some might say to use a computer, but when my computer's down or I am in a trip when I don't have access, this phone is the only thing available to log in to the site. And if ChatJax is disabled or unavailable, it's not pretty.)